# Device tree compiler won't update

Tags: apt, package-management, embedded

I have a problem on Ubuntu 12.04. I am trying to flash a Toradex Colibri T20 with Linux, following these instructions: http://falstaff.agner.ch/2014/03/16/colibri-t20-upstream-linux-kernel/.

However, when I run the

```
make -j 8
```

command, the terminal says, that my DTC version should be 1.4.0 or newer. So I checked with

```
dpkg -s device-tree-compiler | grep Version
```

and the result is

```
Version: 1.3.0-2ubuntu1
```

So I searched on google and found this site: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/device-tree-compiler. The latest stable release is marked as 1.4.0, but when I try to update the package with

```
sudo apt-get install device-tree-compiler
```

it says

```
device-tree-compiler is already the newest version.
```

So what am I missing here, do I have to add a special repository to apt-get in order to get the latest release or something?

Comment: Whether you can compile and run a newer version is a different story, but on the page you linked it clearly shows that `trusty` (your distro version) has exactly the version as latest that you're telling us. Why not use 14.04? The upgrade should be smooth as both are LTS versions.

Comment: O I see it now. I didn't realize that those names were Ubuntu code names. Then I will just update to 14.04 and it should work. Thanks.